# Angular 5 : How to pass classname in providers

Tags: angular

I want to pass a class name inside provider like below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  providers: [Logger('HomeComponent')] <--- class name here
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. How would you use that?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement to achieve. Provider is used to setup input dependency resolution manually rather than have Angular decide the resolved item.

Comment: I want to name of the Class where this provider is used

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to provide a service class -

```
export class HomeComponent {


  constructor(public logger: NGXLogger) {
  }
}
```

OR

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-Home',
  providers: [ NGXLogger ]
)}
```